# why mongoexport behaves this way?

Tags: mongodb

when I run this,

```
mongoexport --db mydb_dev --collection location_updates --csv --fields lat,lon --out location.csv
```

it gives me,

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
exported 0 records
```

However when I move --db to the end and run this,

```
mongoexport --collection location_upates --csv --fields lat,lon --out location.csv --db mydb_dev
```

it gives me,

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
exported 92913 records
```

Any idea why it works like this? Is there ordering of Options important in Mongo?

Comment: I tested the first command with the same database and collection names, and it exports the records correctly. `$ mongoexport --db mydb_dev --collection location_updates --csv --fields lat,lon --out location.csv` `connected to: 127.0.0.1` `exported 1 records`

Comment: Order of options shouldn't be important .. what version of `mongoexport` are you using? Run: `mongoexport --version`.

Comment: @Stennie I'm using version 2.6.1 on windows 7